# php add email to a list file csv

Tags: php, email, csv

I'm trying to build a list email using CSV file , the problem it im using a CMS on simpel site it works !
When i integreted in my cms is stop working and it says :

> Access forbidden!You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.Error 403127.0.0.1Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) PHP/5.5.8

This is my code on the offline page :

```
</div><div class="clear"></div>
    <form name="form1" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" class="subscribe">
        <input type="text" id="notify_by_mail" name="notify_by_mail" class="email"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="GO" class="submit"/>
    </form>
```

This is the php file code :

```
<?php
        if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "GO")
        {
            $varName = $_POST['notify_by_mail'];
            $file = 'user_emails.csv'; /* The .csv file */
            $fs = fopen($file,"a"); /* Opens up the csv file called user_emails.csv. */
            fwrite($fs,$varName . ", \n"); /* And writes the submitted email to it */
            fclose($fs);
            chmod($file,0622); /* Permissions */
        ?>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {

                    /* When the user submits his e-mailaddress successfully, the next comment will show below the form. */
                    $("#notify_by_mail").after("<span class='error'>Your e-mailaddress has been submitted to us.</span>");

                });
            </script>

        <?php
        }
    ?>
```

I'v added to the .htaccess file :

```
<FilesMatch "\.(csv)$|^$">
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

> Access forbidden!You don't have permission to access the requested
>   object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.If
>   you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.Error
>   403127.0.0.1Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) PHP/5.5.8

Can it be from .htaccess ?

Comment: Sounds more like a *nix level permission issue than Apache - odds are your Apache user (probably www-data) doesn't have permissions to write to that file (or directory)... which, considering it appears to be a plain-text document potentially full of email addresses, within the document root, is **not** perhaps a bad thing

Comment: Indeed i'm making tests on a localhost, i'm going to try using it on a online host site, maybe you are right sir and it is from Apache..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a decimal value where you should be using hex.

`chmod($file,0622);` is equivalent to: `chmod($file,0x026E);`

Change:

```
chmod($file,0622);
```

To:

```
chmod($file,0x0622);
```

Not sure you want the chmod after you open and write the file:

```
$varName = $_POST['notify_by_mail'];
$file = 'user_emails.csv'; /* The .csv file */
$fs = fopen($file,"a"); /* Opens up the csv file called user_emails.csv. */
fwrite($fs,$varName . ", \n"); /* And writes the submitted email to it */
fclose($fs);
chmod($file,0622); /* Permissions */
```

You may want to move the chmod up before the open and write.

```
$varName = $_POST['notify_by_mail'];
chmod($file,0622); /* Permissions */
$file = 'user_emails.csv'; /* The .csv file */
$fs = fopen($file,"a"); /* Opens up the csv file called user_emails.csv. */
 fwrite($fs,$varName . ", \n"); /* And writes the submitted email to it */
fclose($fs);
```

If the problem persists, view permissions and file info:

```
echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($file)), -4);
var_dump(stat($file));
```

If you have concerns about public access, move the file to a private directory such as: `/home/user/etc`